# How to generate a treeview from xml file using react.js and asp.net core?

Tags: reactjs

I created a treeview from xml file using javascript and xsl.
Please find the github code: https://github.com/mycodegithub/TreeFromXML_ASP.net

Now I need to convert the same functionality into react. I am new to react. please convert my existing code to react.js.

Please find the tree layout attachment.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAdtd.gif)

Comment: Please see the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Suggesting to use XML to JS object library such as xml2js.

After you convert to JS object you can use the data in your React components.

Read the documentation about xml2js [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js)

Comment: Thanks Yasantha. Please look into my current code. Please help me in converting the code to react.js . I put my current code in github.

Comment: please help me n code